# How do you delete an account from programmers?

Tags: support, user-accounts

How does one delete their account from a specific Stack Exchange site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Meta.StackOverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account):

> How to delete your account:
>
> 1. **Edit your profile to say "please delete me"** so we can confirm your ownership of the account.
> 2. **Obtain your user page URL or numeric user ID**. This is linked from the top of every page of the site, when you are logged in.
> 3. **Email the support address linked at the bottom of every web page** on the site. Where it says "contact us", click that. In your email, you **MUST** include your user page URL or user ID so we can find your account.

Within the Programmers.SE help center, this information can be found at [Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help) > [My Account](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/account) > [How do I delete my account?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)

Comment: I have sent the request to team@stackexchange.com (which was automatically suggested when I clicked the Contact Us). Is that the right address/way?

Comment: What Mark said.  Any moderator can delete accounts, though, so you just need to edit your profile and let some moderator know.  I've taken care of it this time.